# vim inside tmux not rendering proper characters

Tags: debian, vim, tmux, rxvt

I'm trying to run vim inside local tmux session. Vim on its own (both via terminal, and via gui with gvim) is working as expected. I'm running Debian stable, tmux 2.8, vim 8.1.549, urxvt 9.22.

The issue seems that screen isn't always being refreshed where it'd need to be. Particularly noticable when vim buffer gets bigger than screen size.

---

Scenario 1: simply opening vim.

Just in terminal
[image]

In tmux -- text in center missing, or in wrong position (last line)
[image]

---

Scenario 2: opening NERDTree in directory with many files

Just in terminal
[image]

In tmux -- artefacts in main buffer. The file buffer shows wrong lines, as if they all were shifted. Notice how it lacks the "press ? for help" thing at top. The lines are refreshed to correct when go over them with the cursor (I pressed up and down a couple times in second screen shot)
[image]
[image]

---

Scenario 3: writting stuff to main buffer. I pressed 'a' and enter for couple seconds, then 'b' and enter for couple seconds, etc.

Just in terminal
[image]

In tmux -- the old info line is getting dragged along
[image]

---

Also I made observation, that vim stuff leaks outside of tmux into my terminal's scrollback (ie I can see it when I've already exited tmux). Nothing similar happens when using vim without tmux.

---

My .Xresources file:

```
URxvt.font: xft:Monospace-10
URxvt.boldFont: xft:Monospace-10
URxvt.letterSpace: -1
URxvt.scrollBar: false
!urxvt*termname:         rxvt-unicode-256color

!! ================== seoul256 ====================================

! seoul256 (dark) theme adapted for URxvt
URxvt*background: #3a3a3a 
URxvt*foreground: #d0d0d0 
URxvt*color0: #4e4e4e
URxvt*color1: #d68787 
URxvt*color2: #5f865f
URxvt*color3: #d8af5f
URxvt*color4: #85add4
URxvt*color5: #d7afaf
URxvt*color6: #87afaf
URxvt*color7: #d0d0d0
URxvt*color8: #626262
URxvt*color9: #d75f87
URxvt*color10: #87af87
URxvt*color11: #ffd787 
URxvt*color12: #add4fb
URxvt*color13: #ffafaf
URxvt*color14: #87d7d7
URxvt*color15: #e4e4e4
URxvt*cursorColor: #d0d0d0
URxvt*cursorColor2: #3a3a3a
URxvt*colorBD: #e4e4e4
```

My tmux config

```
set -g default-terminal screen-256color
```

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` produce when in tmux and when only in your terminal (outside of tmux)?

Comment: `screen-256color` while inside tmux, `rxvt-unicode-256color` while outside